# How to receive the data sent from Angular to C# webapi?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, api, asp.net-core

I am sending form data to c# core web api via Angular. Console shows the data being sent via service to the api. I am trying to update a value. However, when debugger is kept at the web api controller, the data shows null.
Here is the angular part:

```
this.commonService.updatescheduleFee(this.flatfeeModel).then((response: ResponseModel) => {
            this.toasterMessageService.showSuccess('Fee Schedule Updated Successfully!');
          });
```

Here is the update api being hit with the params:

```
async updatescheduleFee(params: any) {
    params['amount2'] = 100;
    console.log('FeeSchedule-params',params);
    
    return await this.ws.put(`${this.billingApiUrl}/invoice/FeeSchedule`,params).toPromise();
  }
```

Here is the api part where model shows null for the values sent via Angular:

```
[HttpPut("FeeSchedule")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFeeSchedule(FeeScheduleRequest1Dto model)
    {
        try
        {
        }
    }
```

Here is the console screenshot where all the data that is sent to api can be seen:
[image]

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: Can you show the `FeeScheduleRequest1Dto` class? While did you try to add `[FromBody]` attribute? `public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFeeSchedule([FromBody] FeeScheduleRequest1Dto model)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to update a value. However, when debugger is kept at the
> web api controller, the data shows null

I am completely agree with @Yong Shun because you are certainly lacking of [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources) as [toPromise API](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) send request with raw body as like `.put(url, JSON.stringify(pocoModel)`; consequently it wouldn't be able to bind in stricky POCO class if you wouldn't define  [FromBody]. So adding [FromBody]  would resolve your issue.

Demo Model:

```
public class FeeScheduleRequest1Dto
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPut("FeeSchedule")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFeeSchedule([FromBody] FeeScheduleRequest1Dto model)
    {
        try
        {
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

I have tested on my environment here is the exacpected result:

[image]

**Note:** Please have a look on the official document for [angular service update method](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) and [asp.net core [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources) here.